# How to call Python from MATLAB R2019a?

Tags: python, matlab

I have been searching for the way to call Python from MATLAB on Google and YouTube. However, I got confused due to the many ways of doing so.

I have a Python library [DESlib](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/DESlib) downloaded. I have a program from MATLAB that needs that library to perform dynamics classifier selection. No one has developed such a library for MATLAB. I can only found for Python.

So, how I do that call this library from MATLAB?

Answer (score 5):

If your MATLAB version is new enough (the following definitely works on R2019a), MATLAB has builtin support for calling python functions.

Say `module` is your python library that you downloaded and you want to use a function `func` in that module, all you need to do is just

```
py.module.func(<arguments>)
```

See [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-python.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) for more details.

`module` has to be in the python search path, otherwise add it as detailed [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-defined-custom-module.html)